# Get elements that don't contain a figure using plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get all parent items that don't contain a figure. Then I will loop through that and wrap the images inside it in a figure if that figure does not already exist. I have successfully looped through and wrapped each image in a figure however if the figure already exists I want to do skip it. I am hoping to use only javascript and not jquery. Thanks for any help

**HTML**

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <figure class="figure-image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="Image-1" alt="Second Slider Slide">
    </figure>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="Image-2" alt="Second Slider Slide">
</div>
```

**JS**

This JS loops through and wraps all images in a figure but if a figure already exists as per my example above if will add a figure and way resulting in one element having two figures. I think the solution will be to just grab the carosuelItems without .figure-images inside right form the start but I am unsure how to do this.

```
let carouselItem = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slider-image .carousel-item')]

  for (let i = 0; i < carouselItem.length; i++) {
    // Check to see if a figurea lready exists


    // Create a figure for each class and add class to it.
    let figure = document.createElement('figure')
    figure.classList.add('figure-image')
    // Get all images inside of the slider
    let carouselImg = [...carouselItem[i].querySelectorAll('img')]

    for (let img of carouselImg) {
      // Insert the images into each figure
      figure.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', img)
    }

    // Finally insert the figure with the image into each carousel slot
    carouselItem[i].insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', figure)
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you can utilize the [Node.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the element has a child element `<figure>` using something like this: `carouselItem[i].querySelector("figure")`

Here is a complete example:

```js
let carouselItem = [...document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item')]

  for (let i = 0; i < carouselItem.length; i++) {
    if(!carouselItem[i].querySelector("figure")){
      // Check to see if a figurea lready exists


      // Create a figure for each class and add class to it.
      let figure = document.createElement('figure')
      figure.classList.add('figure-image')
      // Get all images inside of the slider
      let carouselImg = [...carouselItem[i].querySelectorAll('img')]

      for (let img of carouselImg) {
        // Insert the images into each figure
        figure.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', img)
      }

      // Finally insert the figure with the image into each carousel slot
      carouselItem[i].insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', figure)
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <figure class="figure-image">
        <img class="Image-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Second Slider Slide">
    </figure>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item">
     <img class="Image-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Second Slider Slide">
</div>
```

Comment: @Greggz It is supposed to show both images, it is supposed to wrap `<img>` elements in `<figure>` elements if that is not the case already.

Comment: Gotcha, tought It was to pick those without the figure class

Comment: This works! thanks. I should have seen that. Case of staring at it too long I guess. I will mark as answer when it will let me!

Answer (score 0):

This is from [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment):

> "Since the **document fragment** is in memory and not part of the main DOM tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow (computation of element's position and geometry). Historically, using document fragments could result in better performance."

In my code I'm using the `createDocumentFragment()` method.

```js
let imgs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("img"));

for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
  let img = imgs[i]
  let parentdiv = img.parentNode;
  if(parentdiv.tagName.toLowerCase() == "figure"){
    continue;
  }else{
    
    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    let figureParent = document.createElement("figure");
    figureParent.setAttribute("class","figure-image");
    figureParent.appendChild(img)
    fragment.appendChild(figureParent);
    parentdiv.appendChild(fragment) 
  }
}
```

```css
figure{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <figure class="figure-image">
        <img class="Image-1" src="https://rpc.virtualhighschool.com/v3_demo/department/demo/course/ver-a/style_template_30/parts-of-a-cell.jpg" alt="Second Slider Slide">
    </figure>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item">
     <img class="Image-2" src="https://rpc.virtualhighschool.com/v3_demo/department/demo/course/ver-a/style_template_30/parts-of-a-cell.jpg" alt="Second Slider Slide">
</div>
```